# Hosting a mongodb based PHP web app

Tags: php, mongodb, web-hosting

How can I host a PHP web application that used MongoDB as database.(I meant NoSQL)
I have built an applcation which is locally running fine, as I will be executing mongod.exe with db path specified.

How can I host the webapp with mongodb that can be accessible like any other normal PHP web app(or website)

Thanks.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/application-hosting/